# Union and value

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
typedef union{
    char a;
    double num;
}uni;
int main(){
    uni name;
    name.num=5.8234;
    printf("%lf\n",name.num);
    name.a='b';
    printf("%lf %c\n",name.num,name.a);
    printf("\n");

}
```

Why does the double number value remain the same?

Output:

```
5.823400
5.823400 b
```

Comment: You are on a little-endian system and changing the char changes only the least significant bits of the double's mantissa. Print your double with a higher precsion, e.g. `"%.20lf"` to see the difference.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your system uses IEEE754 double-precision floating point format for a `double`, the representation of `num` contain 1 sign bit, followed by 11 bits for the exponent, followed by 52 bits for the mantissa.  Also assuming your system uses little-endian byte ordering, the `char` in the union overlays the least significant byte in the `double`, which means the least significant digits change when you change `a`.

You don't see a difference because `%f` only shows 6 decimal digits by default while a `double` with this representation has about 16 significant decimal digits.

If you change the format specifier to `%.16f` you'll see the difference.

```
5.8234000000000004
5.8234000000000794 b
```